# Uploaded @font-face with Base64 encoding blurry in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I use @font-face on Tumblr, with Base64 encoding done with Fontsquirrel web generator so it can work in Firefox, too, and it was working fine for a few months. However, lately, text is blurry, but no everywhere and I don't know what triggered this. I don't think it's latest Firefox update, because it worked fine for some time as I said.
This is how it looks:
[image]

and this is "[live preview](http://tomnno.tumblr.com/)".

So as you can see font is okay on some places but blurry in others.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be your font. Here's a screenshot from IE11 on Windows 7:
[image: IE11 screenshot]

You can see a coloured highlighting effect around the text in different places, consistent with your Firefox screenshot. I think that's caused by bad font hinting for ClearType.

If you normally use Chrome on Windows, it might look "okay", because [Chrome uses GDI+](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692), an old, ugly font-rendering method. Firefox and modern IE use ClearType, which typically looks much better.

*Disclaimer:* I'm not an expert on typography, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I actually only use FF so I know the font worked fine until recently.. So, I'm baffled with what happened.

Comment: It's possible that Firefox dropped the minimum font size for sub-pixel rendering, which has in turn exposed this issue. That's a bit of an educated guess though.

Comment: My other suggestion would be to look at the original font file: does Windows render it correctly? and can you test it on Linux? If it won't render nicely *at that size* in e.g. Notepad.exe on Win Vista/7/8/8.1 with ClearType enabled, it's definitely the font that's broken.

Comment: I tried the font in Notepad.exe and I don't know how to enable/disable ClearType, so I'm not sure if it's good or not, the thing is all pixel/bitmap fonts are with this issue in Firefox, I tested others, too.

Comment: Just typing "ClearType" into the start menu should find the controls to enable/tune it, but it's probably already enabled. I did some searching and turned up [this support thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/795834) which looks similar to your situation, but there's no solution there unfortunately.

Comment: I think Firefox changed something with Base64 encoding when it comes to fonts, and maybe it only shows in pixel fonts, because when embedded on site this font looks fine [look here](http://www.miniml.com/fonts/kroeger0755/) - that's font creator's site, and he says his font are made for web.

Comment: Also that topic isn't very similar to mine because this font worked just fine until very recently.